# fail2ban fails to ban IP with "already banned"

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I enabled the dovecot plugin on my server and after a while (read: 10 seconds), I got my first ban:

```
2020-12-20 08:05:22,349 fail2ban.actions        [1495]: NOTICE  [dovecot] Ban 212.70.149.85
2020-12-20 08:05:22,451 fail2ban.filter         [1495]: INFO    [dovecot] Found 212.70.149.85 - 2020-12-20 08:05:22
2020-12-20 08:05:47,530 fail2ban.filter         [1495]: INFO    [dovecot] Found 212.70.149.85 - 2020-12-20 08:05:47
2020-12-20 08:05:47,842 fail2ban.filter         [1495]: INFO    [dovecot] Found 212.70.149.85 - 2020-12-20 08:05:47
2020-12-20 08:06:38,200 fail2ban.filter         [1495]: INFO    [dovecot] Found 212.70.149.85 - 2020-12-20 08:06:38
2020-12-20 08:06:38,401 fail2ban.filter         [1495]: INFO    [dovecot] Found 212.70.149.85 - 2020-12-20 08:06:38
2020-12-20 08:06:38,891 fail2ban.actions        [1495]: WARNING [dovecot] 212.70.149.85 already banned
```

But as you can see, somehow after 1 minute without being unbanned, it did another 5 tries.

This is from my iptables section:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1816    99591 f2b-dovecot  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995,143,993,587,465,4190
[...]
 
Chain f2b-dovecot (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      31     1770 REJECT     all  --  *      *       212.70.149.70        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       212.70.149.54        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       212.70.149.85        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    1717    93921 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

lsof output:

```
COMMAND  PID FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dovecot 2154 23u  IPv4  24422      0t0  TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
dovecot 2154 24u  IPv6  24423      0t0  TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
dovecot 2154 25u  IPv4  24424      0t0  TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
dovecot 2154 26u  IPv6  24425      0t0  TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
```

- So this looks just fine to me... dovecot is listening on pop3 & pop3s (110 & 995), which are in the dports of multiport.
- ip6 is disabled on this server (for now) so I'm 100% certain it's not going through there
- as lsof shows, it's not listening on UDP

I'm at a loss here: why isn't iptables capturing (and rejecting) the packets? Because as you can see in the iptables, there is another IP which is also blocked and the block is working fine. What makes the 54 & 85 so different?

Is there some way I can debug this?

Other answers included, but were not helpful:

- setting protocol to all: doesn't work with multiport, but doesn't change anything as dovecot is only listening on tcp.
- it's not behind a proxy

Thanks!

Comment: See Dovecot's logs for the same timestamps. Was it really pop3/pop3s that caused this, or is there some other services listening that are not in your `dports` list?

Comment: Thanks a lot @EsaJokinen! Looking carefully through the logs showed me "service=smtp". So somehow, even though it's not listening on that port (postfix is), dovecot is handling the smtp service for (likely local deliveries). Adding that port into the jail fixed it.